# Ember JS: How to bind a model to a select option

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to ember and trying to figure out:

1. How to bind a select option to a specific model.
2. How to update the template with the selected model for a given option.

This is my current code (truncated for brevity). Any help to point me in the right direction appreciated.

Template (EditRoom.hbs):

```
{{view Ember.Select 
  content=options 
  optionValuePath="content.id" 
  optionLabelPath="content.name" 
  prompt="Choose an option..."
}}
<div class="filter">
//This is where the models will be outputed
  {{#each filter1}}<a></a>{{/each}}
  {{#each filter2}}<a></a>{{/each}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
App.EditRoomController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

// Select dropdown
options: [
    {text: "filter1", id: 1},
    {text:"filter2", id: 2}
]});
```

Route:

```
App.EditRoomRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      filter1: this.store.find('filter1'),
      filter2: this.store.find('filter2')
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI- Your `optionLabelPath` is "content.name" but your data uses the property `text`.

Comment: @Steve H - Thanks, will update that.